# calling function of one class from other class

Tags: java, android, class

I have a class called SResponses which has the function "getsrthreadid" and I am trying to call it from my other class,I am doing it as:

```
SResponses sres=new SResponses();
String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_POSITION + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+ "="+sres.getsrthreadid();

//Log.e("datasource", sres.getsrthreadid());
cursors = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
```

Function in SResponses class is defined as:

```
private String threadid;

public String  getsrthreadid()
{
    return threadid;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sresponses);
    datasource = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
    datasource.open();

    Intent intent=getIntent();

    threadid = intent.getStringExtra("threadid"); 
}
```

But I am getting no value from this function.Please help me find out the problem.

**Error from Logcat**:

```
 11-07 01:43:01.072: E/AndroidRuntime(848): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.SResponses}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Comment: And where are you setting the threadid value?

Comment: How you know it is not returning anything? Did you use debugger and stepped through the code?

Comment: I might be able to answer if you tell where `queryz` is and what it is.

Comment: @Prateek Maybe he did some sort of output. He doesn't have to show that part of the code.

Comment: @Prateek There is no sign of him initializing that value with anything so more than likely he's correct regardless of whether he checked it. Based on what he's shown us he should be expecting `null` instead of a value.

Comment: @izuriel Exactly my point. If he did use debugger he can spot that issue in a blink of eye.

Comment: @Prateek i used logcat when i tried to print this value in log cat it give me this error:
11-07 01:43:01.072: E/AndroidRuntime(848): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.SResponses}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: @Talib Can you show where you are putting in the value for `threadid`

Comment: @Talib Where do you set the value of `"threadid"` in the `Intent`? Are you sure you're setting it before you get to this view?

Comment: @Talib Well based on the amount of code you've given us I can only guess that you're not setting the intent's value before you get here, or you're using different names for the values name. If you could please create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating this problem I can help you further (that includes a view setting the value, and a view accessing the value.